# Append data to a CSV file on an FTP server using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, ftp, append, webclient

I am trying to append data to a CSV file on an FTP server using PowerShell.
Currently my script works fine, however it is overwriting the data.

Here is the main bit of my code:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 

$UserInfo = [pscustomobject]@{
    UserName = $env:UserName
    ComputerName = $env:computername
}
    
$contents =
   (($UserInfo | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join [Environment]::NewLine) + 
   [Environment]::NewLine
$webclient.UploadString(($ftp + "/Installed.csv"), $contents)
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this without any native plugins or libraries. The only other thing I can think of is using something like `get-content` to get the current data from the file, and then the new data would be
`getcontent myfile.csv` + the new data from `$UserInfo`

Basically I am installing a VPN through group policy and would like to log who successfully installed the client. We don't have any software distribution platforms unfortunately so we're trying to use GP and FTP to perform this task.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with `WebClient`. But it can be done with [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest) and [`WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.appendfile).

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("ftp://example.com/remote/path/file.txt")
$request.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
$request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::AppendFile 

$ftpStream = $request.GetRequestStream()

$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($ftpStream)
$writer.Write($contents)
$writer.Close()

$ftpStream.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. Everything is working properly.